# How to write a unittest for script using pygame, and members like pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pygame

I am making a simple game of Connect 4 in python and am using pygame for GUI, but I cannot seems to find a way to write unit test for the same

Here is a link to my python script [script](https://github.com/Kartikei-12/Connect-N/blob/master/connect_n/pygame_utility.py)

Link to my [project](https://github.com/Kartikei-12/Connect-N)

For method like,

```
def play(self, board, players, is_valid_move, make_move, is_winning_move):
        """Method to play the game in GUI using pygame

        Note:
            When playing with AI a mouse click is required to trigger AI move

        Args:
            board (numpy.ndarray): Game board
            players (list): List of players
            is_valid_move (function): Move validator
            make_move (function): Makes move
            is_winning_move (function): Ckeck for winning move"""
        turn = random.randint(0, len(players) - 1)
        while True:
            self.draw(board)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return None

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                    self.draw_black_rec()
                    self.draw_player_coin(players[turn].p_id, event)
                pygame.display.update()

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    self.draw_black_rec()
                    if players[turn].name == "AI":
                        col = players[turn].get_move()
                    if is_valid_move(col):
                        row = make_move(col, players[turn].p_id)
                    turn = (turn + 1) % len(players)
```

I expect to write a unittest testing the above functionality, it will also work if I cannot test whole method just part of it.

Comment: I think you have to `init()` pygame, create screen and use second `thread` which will use [pygame.event.post](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.post) to create event `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. But this way you can get only result at the end of game. You can't get result after every frame. In `gym.AI` (which is used for `Reinforcement Learning` in games) is used function `render()` which render single frame. Maybe you should put code from `while True` in function  `render()` and run `while True: render()` and then you can use `render()` to easily test with single frame.

Comment: thanks man!!, trying threaded solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) objects of any type with any required attributes. Place the events in the queue with [`pygame.event.post`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Eventv).

e.g:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()    
pygame.event.get()

post_event = pygame.event.Event(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, button = 2, pos = (5, 5))
pygame.event.post(post_event)
event = pygame.event.poll()

result = event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 2 and event.pos == (5, 5)
print(result)

pygame.quit()
```